# Prove if $d \mid mn$ when $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ , then $\gcd(d, mn) = d$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This seems pretty obvious to me, but I'm having hard time coming with a proof. Could you please help me?

Comment: ??  If $d|N$ then $\gcd(d,N) = d$ with NO conditions on $N$. Can you prove *that*?

Comment: No. I think the fact that m and n are relatively prime in the question makes no difference. Help?

Comment: Is the question correct as asked? @mathguy 's comment should be a red flag since a piece of the question is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: the question is rather trivial but it is certainly on topic. I don't see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gcd must divide $d$ so it is less than or equal to $d.$ $d$ divides both $d$ and $mn$ so the gcd is $d$.

Comment: I understand it. Thank you.

Comment: you may find my book "proof patterns' helpful.